# NullReference when creating custom page

Tags: content-type, page-layout

I am trying to display content in a formatted, custom page in SP10.

I created a content type, I'll call BobType, which uses "Page" as the parent (actually, i've tried it with "Enterprise Wiki Page" as well) and has one added field, Description.

Using SPD, I created a page layout based on Bobtype called BobTypeLayout which contains the Name, Description, Rollup Image, and Comments fields.  I then checked it in and approved the file.

Next, I went to site administration | site libraries and lists | customize "Pages" and added BobType to the allowed list.  I made it the default type.

Now, I head back to the main site and select site actions | new page and create BobTest.  It returns the correct form for creating a new BobType.  So far, everything seems to be going great.

After filling in the form with random data - about you know who - I click save and get the infamous, "An unexpected error has occurred."

ULS viewer on the server shows that I'm getting:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiPageWebPartSaver.SaveWebPartsInRichText(SPWebPartManager wpmgr)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPPageStateControl.EnsureItemSavedIfEditMode(Boolean forceSave, String overwriteCommandHandler, String discardChangesCommandHandler)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveAndStopEditCommandHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageSaveAndStopEditHandler.BaseRaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.RaisePostBackEventForPageRouting(String eventArgument, SPRibbonCommandHandler control, RaisePostBackEventDelegate raisePostBackEventDelegate)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageSaveAndStopEditHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I've been tweaking the procedure randomly for a couple hours but seem to get stuck at the same point each time.  The only requred field on the content type is, Name, and it has a value.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?  I can provide more info if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stack trace seems to reference the Wiki Pahe content type... Is that the case? Was the error any different when you used the "Page" content type as parent?

Comment: Yes, the error was the same with Page.  I tried a few options and did not remember where I left off.

Comment: I have same issue. Any body can help me

Answer (score 0):

I find a link: http://spfarm.blogspot.com/2011/05/sharepoint-object-reference-not-set-to.html.

It's resolved my issue.